# PHP + MySQL - Erro de sintaxe com aspas na String

Tags: php, mysql, sintaxe

"obs: quando a string não tem aspas simples, isso funciona perfeitamente, meu problema é quando tem aspas simples"

exemplo com aspas simples:

```
$name = "Michael";
$store = "Mike's Store";

"INSERT INTO database(name, store) VALUES('$name', '$store')";
```

com isso, acontece um erro de sintaxe, por que os VALUES na verdade está passando assim:

```
"INSERT INTO database(name, store) VALUES('Michael', 'Mike's Store')";
```

como a string `#store` tem uma aspas simples, isso dá conflito com as outras aspas simples, acontecendo o erro:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 's Store' at line 1`

Já tentei usar backstricks nos nomes das colunas e acontece o mesmo erro:

```
"INSERT INTO database(`name`, `store`) VALUES('Michael', 'Mike's Store')";
```

Já tentei usar backstricks no lugar as aspas simples, em VALUES:

```
"INSERT INTO database(name, store) VALUES(`$name`, `$store`)";
```

mas acontece este erro no MySQL(acredito que em todas as colunas):

```
Unknown column 'mike' in 'field list'
```

e é isso...

no DB, existe alguma forma de armazenar uma string que contenha aspas simples?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Tente "escapar" os caracteres:

```
function escape_mimic($inp) { 
    if(is_array($inp)) 
        return array_map(__METHOD__, $inp); 

    if(!empty($inp) && is_string($inp)) { 
        return str_replace(array('\\', "\0", "\n", "\r", "'", '"', "\x1a"), array('\\\\', '\\0', '\\n', '\\r', "\\'", '\\"', '\\Z'), $inp); 
    } 

    return $inp; 
} 

echo escape_mimic("Esse é um tes't feito");
```

Output:

> Esse é um tes\'t feito

Comment: cara, muito obrigado, resolveu o problema.

Answer (score 2):

O *mysqli* possui um recurso que é justamente para este proposito, o [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, "Michael");
$store =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, "Mike's Store");
```

<sub>O `$conexão` é o link do mysqli, iniciado por `mysqli_connect`.</sub>

---

Apenas para complementar o uso deste recurso irá dificultar (*"impedir"*) ataques de SQL Injection, desde que definido um [`mysqli_set_charset`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.set-charset.php) corretamente, como está na documentação.

Além disso, supondo que o "Michael" for dinâmico, *inserido pelo usuário*, o `mysqli_real_escape_string` não impede ataques do tipo XSS, para isso utilize em conjunto o [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.htmlentities.php) na saída do texto, quanto for exibi-lo.

Answer (score 0):

Para escapar `'` utilize `addslashes()` o mesmo insere uma barra `\` que escapa o valor.

exemplo:

```
$name = "My name is D'Orail";
echo addslashes($name);
//result 
# My name is D\'Orail
```

Acesse a [documentação para maiores informações](http://br.php.net/addslashes)

Dessa forma o conteúdo poderá ser salvo sem problemas.